# Send data to MQTT broker using SIM800 and ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, mqtt, sim800

I'm working on a project in which I need to send data to an MQTT broker installed on a Raspberry Pi.

I refer to the tinyGSM library and [this tutorial](https://microdigisoft.com/esp32-ttgo-t-call-sim800l-with-mqtt-broker-without-wifi/) along with [this example.](https://github.com/vshymanskyy/TinyGSM/tree/master/examples/MqttClient)

[image]

The ESP32 remains in infinite restart mode.

I would like to know if anyone has already tried this library.  How can you configure the pin power motioned here?

My program:

```
// Select your modem:
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800
// Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial

// Set serial for AT commands (to the module)
// Use Hardware Serial on Mega, Leonardo, Micro
#ifndef __AVR_ATmega328P__
#define SerialAT Serial1

// or Software Serial on Uno, Nano
#else
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SerialAT(2, 3);  // RX, TX
#endif

// See all AT commands, if wanted
// #define DUMP_AT_COMMANDS

// Define the serial console for debug prints, if needed
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG SerialMon

// Range to attempt to autobaud
// NOTE:  DO NOT AUTOBAUD in production code.  Once you've established
// communication, set a fixed baud rate using modem.setBaud(#).
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN 9600
#define GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX 115200
#define TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS true
#define TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI false
const char apn[]      = "iamgprs1.ma";
const char gprsUser[] = "";
const char gprsPass[] = "";
const char wifiSSID[] = "YourSSID";// Your WiFi connection credentials, if applicable
const char wifiPass[] = "YourWiFiPass";
// MQTT details
const char* broker = "192.168.1.111";// Public IP address or domain name
const char* topicLed = " esp32/output";
const char* Topic_Temperature = "esp32/temperature";
const char* Topic_Humidity = "esp32/humidity";
/*
const char* topicLed       = " esp32/output";
const char* topicInit      = "GsmClientTest/init";
const char* topicLedStatus = "GsmClientTest/ledStatus"; */
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
#include <StreamDebugger.h>
StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, SerialMon);
TinyGsm        modem(debugger);
#else
TinyGsm        modem(SerialAT);
#endif
TinyGsmClient client(modem);
PubSubClient  mqtt(client);

uint32_t lastReconnectAttempt = 0;

void mqttCallback(char* topic, byte* message, unsigned int len) {
  SerialMon.print("Message arrived [");
  SerialMon.print(topic);
  SerialMon.print("]: ");
  SerialMon.write(message, len);
  SerialMon.println();
    String messageTemp;
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)message[i]);
     messageTemp += (char)message[i];
  // Only proceed if incoming message's topic matches
  if (String(topic) == " esp32/output") {
        Serial.print("Changing output to ");
    if(messageTemp == "on"){
      Serial.println("on");
      
    }
    else if(messageTemp == "off"){
      Serial.println("off");
    
    }
  
  }
}
}

boolean mqttConnect() {
  SerialMon.print("Connecting to ");
  SerialMon.print(broker);

  // Connect to MQTT Broker
  //boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientTest");

  // Or, if you want to authenticate MQTT:
  boolean status = mqtt.connect("GsmClientName", "username", "user");

  if (status == false) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    return false;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
  mqtt.publish( "esp32/temperature","32");
  mqtt.publish("esp32/humidity", "80");
  return mqtt.connected();
}


void setup() {
  // Set console baud rate
  SerialMon.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  #define RXD2 16
  #define TXD2 17


  SerialMon.println("Wait...");

  // Set GSM module baud rate
  TinyGsmAutoBaud(SerialAT, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MIN, GSM_AUTOBAUD_MAX);
  // SerialAT.begin(9600);
  delay(6000);

  // Restart takes quite some time
  // To skip it, call init() instead of restart()
  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.restart();
  // modem.init();

  String modemInfo = modem.getModemInfo();
  SerialMon.print("Modem Info: ");
  SerialMon.println(modemInfo);

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
  // Unlock your SIM card with a PIN if needed
  //if (GSM_PIN && modem.getSimStatus() != 3) { modem.simUnlock(GSM_PIN); }
#endif

#if TINY_GSM_USE_WIFI
  // Wifi connection parameters must be set before waiting for the network
  SerialMon.print(F("Setting SSID/password..."));
  if (!modem.networkConnect(wifiSSID, wifiPass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");
#endif

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS && defined TINY_GSM_MODEM_XBEE
  // The XBee must run the gprsConnect function BEFORE waiting for network!
  modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass);
#endif

  SerialMon.print("Waiting for network...");
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork()) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) { SerialMon.println("Network connected"); }

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
  // GPRS connection parameters are usually set after network registration
  SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
  SerialMon.print(apn);
  if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
    SerialMon.println(" fail");
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }
  SerialMon.println(" success");

  if (modem.isGprsConnected()) { SerialMon.println("GPRS connected"); }
#endif

  // MQTT Broker setup
  mqtt.setServer(broker, 1883);
  mqtt.setCallback(mqttCallback);
}

void loop() {
  // Make sure we're still registered on the network
  if (!modem.isNetworkConnected()) {
    SerialMon.println("Network disconnected");
    if (!modem.waitForNetwork(180000L, true)) {
      SerialMon.println(" fail");
      delay(10000);
      return;
    }
    if (modem.isNetworkConnected()) {
      SerialMon.println("Network re-connected");
    }

#if TINY_GSM_USE_GPRS
    // and make sure GPRS/EPS is still connected
    if (!modem.isGprsConnected()) {
      SerialMon.println("GPRS disconnected!");
      SerialMon.print(F("Connecting to "));
      SerialMon.print(apn);
      if (!modem.gprsConnect(apn, gprsUser, gprsPass)) {
        SerialMon.println(" fail");
        delay(10000);
        return;
      }
      if (modem.isGprsConnected()) { SerialMon.println("GPRS reconnected"); }
    }
#endif
  }

  if (!mqtt.connected()) {
    SerialMon.println("=== MQTT NOT CONNECTED ===");
    // Reconnect every 10 seconds
    uint32_t t = millis();
    if (t - lastReconnectAttempt > 10000L) {
      lastReconnectAttempt = t;
      if (mqttConnect()) { lastReconnectAttempt = 0; }
    }
    delay(100);
    return;
  }

  mqtt.loop();
}
```

Comment: ESP32 has debug capability.  Can you step through it until you find the offending section of code?

Comment: I think the problem starts from the Sim800 modem initialization                                                        SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");
  modem.restart();
  //modem.init();

Comment: Can you step into that code?

Comment: I'm working on ARDUINO IDE I think i can't step into

Comment: Maybe update to PIO, it's worth it.